# alert when value changed setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, setinterval, getjson

When there is an update from getjson, the textbox text changed!
No allert is comminh up.. some one can help me with this allert??
The textbox:

```
<input id="your_textbox" />

  setInterval(function () {
      $.getJSOg('/api/my_apiurl', function (Payload) {
          $(Payload).each(function (i, item) {
              $("#your_textbox").val(item.CR_DateTime);
          });
      });
  }, 3000);
```

and the script to allert "haai:

```
setInterval(function () {
  jQuery('#your_textbox').on('input', function () {
      alert('haai');
  });
 }, 3000);
```

Change to (not working):

```
   setInterval(function () {
 var check;
$(function(checkForMessages) {    
          $.getJSON('/api/myapiurl', function (data) {
if(data == 1) {
            //There are new messages
            clearInterval(check);
            alert("You have mail!");
        }
    }
);

check = setInterval(checkForMessages, 3000);

   });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Yep, the apicall is working and the value your_textbox changed  (date)

Comment: The problem is: i am looking fo a  solution "there is a new message" hope this wil help my question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You keep adding an even to the textbox over and over and over again! That is really bad.

It should just be

```
jQuery('#your_textbox').on('input', function () {
    alert('haai');
});
```

Now JavaScript does not trigger the event when you change the textbox with code, so you need to do the triggering.

```
var previousValue = $("#your_textbox").val(),
    newValue = item.CR_DateTime;
if (previousValue !== newValue ) {
    $("#your_textbox").val(newValue).trigger("input");
}
```

Comment: Well you can add a check to see if the value changed before triggering. Edited the code in the question to show you want to do.